# How does punctuation affect this clause in a sentence?

Tags: grammar, punctuation, sentence

In this sentence:

> Parents and children, under the age of 18, that live in the same residence

When punctuated this way, does the age restriction apply to both parents and children? I mean, obviously it doesn't in reality. I'm just wondering how to properly punctuate the sentence to reflect the actual policy.

Answer (score 1):

It would be cleaner to say:

> Parents, and children under the age of 18 that live in the same residence[, ...]